# I want to grep some text using regex. But it is not working

Tags: python, regex

I have to grep some text for that I have written regex format in python script to grep that text. But it is not grep the text what I want.

`n="<directory>regression\UC400_019_TC15</directory>" Rep_str = re.findall(r"\b<directory>\w*</directory>\b",n) print(Rep_str)`

I want to grep the text in between " and <\directory>" for that i made re.findall, where, "Rep_str" is not giving any value. It is printing null string. So anyone can help me how can i grep the text in between the " and <\directory>" directories.

I have tried to grep the text in between the " and <\directory>". where it is giving empty string. so How can i grep that text in between the " and <\directory>" directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression and use the **.group(1)** method to get the text:

```
r'<directory>(.*?)</directory>'
```

Comment: I want to grep the directory lines "<directory>&</directory>" from the xml file on that time i am getting an error like this:
Enter the XML file:C:\HSS\cntdb_aep_ci\test\LI_3GPPHSS\scheduler\regression\FC122_004770-China_LI_2.xml
True
<regression target-line="li_3gpphss" phase="p7">

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rohithgu\Desktop\GIM_IDEA\GenerateFolderResponse.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(Rep_str.group(1))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: The error is because it is not returing any value from "Rep_str.group(1)". you can see that it is checking from the frist
line of the file on from the entire file. So how can i resolve these issue. to check from the enitre file and give the string.

If i give the string to the line directly then that time it is giving the output what i want. If i search from the file then 
that time i am getting an error like above.

Comment: This is the code for the above error.

import os
import sys
import shutil
import re

str11=input("Enter the XML file:")
file_exist = os.path.isfile(str11)
file_exists=str(file_exist)
print(file_exists)
if file_exists=='True':
  f1=open(str11,'r')
  for line in f1:
     print(line)
     Rep_str=re.match(r'<directory>(.*?)</directory>',line)
     print(Rep_str.group(1))